# PowerShell GraphQL Mutation Parsing Error

Tags: powershell, graphql

I'm querying the Monday API v2 (https://monday.com/developers/v2) I'm getting stuck in getting the PowerShell query to work, the script is below:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
    $url = "https://api.monday.com/v2/"
    $hdr = @{ }
    $hdr.Add("Authorization", "redacted")
    $hdr.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    $bodytxt = '{"query":"mutation{change_column_value (board_id: 528033866, item_id: 574335355, column_id: \"status_1\", value: "{\"index\": 1}") {id}}"}'
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $hdr -Method Post -body $bodytxt
    Write-Host $response
```

And it keeps returning

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on \": 1}\" (STRING) at [1, 110]","locations":[{"line":1,"column":110}]}],"account_id":5305133}
```

The mutation query in Postman works fine

```
change_column_value (board_id: 528033866, item_id: 574335355, column_id: "status_1", value: "{\"index\": 1}"){id}
}
```

I have tried working with what quotes are escaped, but I still haven't been able to get it to run succesfully. I was referencing the tips here https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b9jasa/query_graphql_with_powershell/

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add the current query (not mutation) that works fine through Powershell

```
$bodytxt = '{"query":"{  boards (ids: 528033866) {    groups (ids: \"group_title\"){        items () {            id            name       updates () {  body }     column_values () {        id        title        value    text  }        }        title    }    }  }"}'
```

Comment: `$bodytext` is not a valid JSON string. Did you try `$Body = @{ query = ' ...` in the reddit link?

Comment: I did not as I understood that the the body isn't necessarily a correctly formed JSON request. I did give it a try though, however it started throwing more errors. Yesterday was a long day so I forgot to add the query (not a mutation) in the edit above that works correctly.

Comment: don't forget to stringify `$bodytxt = $Body | ConvertTo-Json`. 
The idea is first creating a hashtable, then convert it to a JSON string.
The second $bodytxt is valid as `$bodytxt | ConvertFrom-Json` runs successfully.

Comment: `"{\"index\": 1}"` → `\"{\\\"index\\\":1}\"` works for me.

Comment: That was it, I hadn't escaped the slashes, thanks! So if I am able to have the correct query returned when I pipe it through 'ConvertFrom-Json' it should always work in the API call with the GraphQL?

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a GraphQL query is

1. create a hashtable with [HERE-STRINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#here-strings)
2. convert it to a JSON string with `ConvertTo-Json`.

```bsh
$bodytxt = @{"query" = @'
  mutation {
    change_column_value(
      board_id: 123123
      item_id: 456456
      column_id: "status1"
      value: "{\"index\":1}"
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
'@
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

White spaces inside `@'...'@` are optional.

---

reply to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960272/powershell-graphql-mutation-parsing-error?noredirect=1#comment109662043_61960272)

> it should always work in the API call with the GraphQL?

I think it depends on services, but in most cases, yes. `application/json` is the GraphQL default content type for the request body.

and for [monday.com](https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005144659-Does-monday-com-have-an-API-)

> Be sure to use the application/json content type